# How to reconfigure regions live with Android Beacon Library?

Tags: android, altbeacon

I'm trying to make an app that can dynamically change what beacon region is monitored.
Especially, I need to use MAC-address based regions. The use case is not actually beacons, instead we're researching using BLE advertising for transmission of IoT data. However the beacons use case is so close that using Android Beacon Library made perfect sense.

Everything works perfectly when statically configured, but if I try to edit the region at runtime it changes absolutely nothing, the results are just like before requested change.

I have methods like this to change the region (this is for only one at time, but I'll need a list of MACs when I get this working):

```
  fun disableMonitoring() {
        if (regionBootstrap != null) {
            regionBootstrap.disable()
        }
    }

   fun enableMonitoring() {
        
        regionBootstrap.removeRegion(region)
        region = Region("wildcard-region", null, null, null)
        regionBootstrap.addRegion(region)
        regionBootstrap = RegionBootstrap(this, region)
    }

   fun enableListening(mac: String) {
        
        regionBootstrap.removeRegion(region)
        region = Region("regionForMacAddress", mac)
        regionBootstrap.addRegion(region)
        regionBootstrap = RegionBootstrap(this, region)
    }
```

I checked that using the disable method makes no difference, and also tried using just add/removeRegion methods without rerunning bootstrap. No luck.

I'm running this on Samsung S9 Android 10, using 2.18-beta library. I started simply by hacking the Kotlin example code from GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

In general the RegionBootstrap class should not have more than one instance per app.  It should be constructed exactly once the first time you start looking for beacons.  After that, you can call `addRegion(…)` and `removeRegion(…)` on the single instance.

**EDIT: Take care to change the string `uniqueId` of the region** (the first parameter) each time you create a different one.  Two distinct region definitions sharing the same uniqueId will be treated as a single region.  It will fail to change the region.  You can use the MAC address as this parameter as well to make it easier for your use case.

Also, be aware that **the only time you will need to create a new instance of RegionBootstrap if you ever call the `regionBootstrap.disable()` method**.  In this case you do need to construct a new instance to get it going again.  Failure to do so in this case will give you an error about the consumer not being bound.  (Unless you have a good reason, simply do not call `regionBootstrap.disable()`.

While the above use should work, the `RegionBootstrap` construct really is designed for more static monitoring which is why this seems so awkward.  If you frequently want to change the monitored regions, you are better off not using `RegionBootstrap` at all and instead using these APIs:

```
beaconManager.bind(this)  // call just one time at app start then wait for  the onBeaconServiceConnected callback
beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region) // add a new region
//then later
beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(newRegion) // add a new region
beaconManager.stopMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region)
```

Still too awkward?  The library also has even simpler [autobind APIs](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/pull/1035)
in the latest 2.19-beta4 release.  These eliminate the need to call bind manually and wait for the callback.  These are still beta because I have not thoroughly tested them in your case where regions are changed at great frequency.  Feel free to try if you wish and report back any problems:

```
beaconManager.startMonitoringBeacons(region) // add a first region
//then later
beaconManager.startMonitoringBeacons(newRegion) // start monitoring second region
beaconManager.stopMonitoringBeacons(region) // remove original  region
```

In general **it is always better to add the new region before removing the old region**, as it lets the library know you are not done scanning beacons entirely.

Comment: I tried that as well by commenting those out. Does not help.

Comment: When I call those methods, I see some warnings in the log:
W/BeaconManager: The BeaconManager is not bound to the service.  Call beaconManager.bind(BeaconConsumer consumer) and wait for a callback to onBeaconServiceConnect()

Comment: Thanks for good explanation! One requirement is that monitoring must happen on background, when device is locked. I gathered RegionBootstrap would be needed for that?

Comment: RegionBootstrap is just a helper class that wraps a call to start monitoring.   As of library version 2.19-beta5, the new and much simpler "autobind" methods work both in the foreground and the background.  No need to manually construct RegionBootstrap anymore.  You just need to call `beaconManager.startMonitoring(region)` and set up your monitor notifier in the application `onCreate()` method -- the same place where you would have constructed RegionBootstrap before.